# Import package from another module

Tags: go, desktop-application, wails

I have to create a desktop app on top of existing Go backend code, since this requirement and my knowledge in web development I'm using [Wails](https://wails.app/).

With Wails CLI I generated the desktop app project in a subfolder of the back end main project.
This is how the folder structure looks like:

```
backend
├── [...]
├── logger
│   └── logger.go
├── gui
│   └── desktopApp
│       ├── build
│       │   └── desktopApp
│       ├── frontend
│       │   └── [...]
│       ├── go.mod
│       ├── go.sum
│       ├── main.go
│       └── project.json
├── main.go
├── go.mod
└── go.sum
```

The `logger` has been imported in the desktopApp and everything works during the development and testing via browser. But when I build the desktop app with the command `wails build` from the desktopApp folder I have got the following error:

```
go: <domain>/<owner>/backend/logger: unrecognized import path "<domain>/<owner>/backend"
```

I imported the backend in the desktop app like this:

/backend/gui/desktopApp/go.mod

```
module desktopApp

go 1.15

require (
    <domain>/<owner>/backend v0.0.0
)
```

./gui/desktopApp/main.go

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/leaanthony/mewn"
    "github.com/wailsapp/wails"

    "<domain>/<owner>/backend/logger"
)

// Using the logger package normally
```

How can I fix my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue changing `go.mod` file of the nested desktop app like this:

```
module desktopApp

go 1.15

require (
    <domain>/<owner>/backend/logger
)
// Added this line
replace <domain>/<owner>/backend/logger => ../../
```

Answer (score 2):

I see that you use `go-module` and store code in a `repo` with `sub-module`

The problem is that you forgot add "desktopApp"-prefix

```
import (
    "github.com/leaanthony/mewn"
    "github.com/wailsapp/wails"

    "desktopApp/backend/backendPackage"
)
```

Right way use [modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules)

Fix `go.mod` of `desktopApp` module

```
module <domain>/<owner>/desktopApp

go 1.15
```

fix `backend`s import , because it belongs to `desktopApp`

```
import (
    "github.com/leaanthony/mewn"
    "github.com/wailsapp/wails"

    "<domain>/<owner>/desktopApp/backend/backendPackage"
)
```

Comment: I edited the question because probably it was not clear. `backend` is the existing repo and I created the `desktopApp` as sub-module. Anyway I'm trying to fix it with your hint.